# Extending a non-Generic to a generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I have this code that represents a non-generic Struct:

```
struct rum {
    var prop = "Hello"
}
```

let's suppose that I need to create an extension for this Struct to receive generic types. For this, I try this code:

```
extension rum <T>{

    func release(bo: T){
        println(T)
    }

}
```

But Xcode gives me many errors, that **rum** does not have a generic type. But the idea is to create a non-generic Struct and transform it into a generic. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If `rum` were a class, you would get more flexibility, because you could derive a generic class from it, and define an extension on that generic class. However, `struct` is a value type, so you cannot derive a class from it.

Since `rum` is not generic `struct`, you need to make the extension method generic, like this:

```
extension rum {

    func release<T>(bo: T){
        println(prop)
        println(bo)
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, this means that all extension methods that you wish to be generic need to be decorated with `<T>`.